# Falling Platform using rigidbody

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a platform that i want to fall once the player has stepped on it. It has two box colliders. One for it's physical being and the other as a trigger. It also has a rigidbody which is kinematic by default so it doesn't fall straight away. However when the player steps on it it does nothing. Can any one tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
var yourObject : GameObject;
 function OnTriggerEnter(Other : Collider){

 if(Other.gameObject.tag == "Player"){

 yourObject.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;

 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plase check your gameobjects tag.

and also i see you use Rigidbody2D so you don't add below

```
 var yourObject : GameObject;
 function OnTriggerEnter(Other : Collider){
    if(Other.gameObject.tag == "Player"){ 
       yourObject.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
    }

 }
```

You need to use [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html)

```
function OnTriggerEnter2D(other: Collider2D) {
     if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player"){ 
           yourObject.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
     }
}
```

And also please check you add tag to gameobjects (I think you mean check names)

Like

```
function OnTriggerEnter2D(other: Collider2D) {
     if(other.gameObject.name == "Player"){  //check name
           yourObject.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a falling platform of sorts you do not have to make use of the `IsKinematic` function.

Instead, you can just turn off the `Use Gravity` function. This will prevent the object from falling, until another object with a rigidbody and a mass bigger then the mass of the platform touches it. As can be seen in the GIF below.
[image]